# Sign AWS requests using Cognito Your User Pool user using Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send an authenticated request to AWS API Gateway. The clients will authenticate against Cognito Your User Pools, and then obtain a token from an associated Cognito Identity Pool corresponding to the logged-in user in the user pool. I am trying to simulate such a request using Postman.

[This post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=700620) suggests that the command `aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity` can be used to get the AccessKeyId and SecretKey needed for Postman to sign the request. However, when I try to run it with the `sub` attribute for a user from the Cognito User Pool console:

```
$ aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity --identity-id aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetCredentialsForIdentity operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee' at 'identityId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+

$ aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity --identity-id us-east-1:aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetCredentialsForIdentity operation: Identity 'us-east-1:aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee' not found.
```

The same thing happens if I try to use an identity ID from the associated identity pool shown in the AWS Console (I selected one that has 2 "linked logins").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass along the login map :

```
--logins (map)
A  set  of  optional  name-value  pairs  that  map provider names to
provider tokens.

Shorthand Syntax:

    KeyName1=string,KeyName2=string

JSON Syntax:

    {"string": "string"
        ...}
```

This syntax worked for me:

```
aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity \
    --identity-id us-east-1:aaaa-bbb-ccc-bc54-rrrrrrr \
    --logins graph.facebook.com=kdajbdjkabkjbkjbkdbsckslcjxb
```

Note: `--identity-id` is not the identity pool id, its the identity from the identity browser.

Answer (score 1):

API gateway now has native integration with 'Cognito Your User Pool', so you can pass the identity token directly - [api gateway docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html). The post you have linked is outdated

Comment: It is not outdated per se because it is still valid for IAM authentication, which we are using, and IAM authentication is still used for social logins (Facebook etc.)

Comment: This answer is closer to my problem - how to get JWT from postman, or shell programmatically, So that I have it for postman/newman to put in the Authentication header.